# Separating $DSPACE(f)$ and $DTIME(2^f)$: is there any function computable in time $2^{O(f)}$ but not in space $O(f)$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

For $f(n)\ge n$,

$$\mathsf{DSPACE}(f(n)) \subseteq \mathsf{DTIME}(2^{O(f(n))}).$$

Is there any function $f$ for which this containment is known to be proper?

Comment: Hmmm, $f(n) = O(1)$ :).

Comment: @RB The containment is not proper for $f(n)=O(1)$.  In fact, there isn't containment at all: constant space includes all regular languages; constant time includes only those languages decidable by looking at a constant prefix of the string.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, the containment is only valid for $f(n)\ge n$. I have corrected the question. Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's valid for $\:\: f(n) \: \geq \: c\hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.03 in}\log(n)\;\;$. $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: What precisely do you mean with $DTIME(2^{O(f(n))})$?  Do you mean that for every $f$ there is some constant $C_f$ such that $DSPACE(f(n)) \subseteq DTIME(2^{C_f f(n)})$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: $DTIME(2^{O(f(n))})$ is too imprecise: this is convenient shorthand, but here it matters what it stands for.  A possible phrasing: "For any function $f(n)\ge n$, there exist constants $C$ such that $DSPACE(f(n)) \subseteq DTIME(2^{Cf(n)})$.  Let $c_f$ be the infimum of all such $C$.  Is there a function $f(n) \ge n$ such that $DSPACE(f(n)) \ne DTIME(2^{c_f f(n)})$ is known to hold?"  Note also that by the time hierarchy theorem, $DTIME(2^{cn}) \subsetneq DTIME(2^{(c+\epsilon)n})$ for any $\epsilon > 0$: even if equality holds for some constant, it will not hold for any others.

Comment: Good point. I disagree with what I said earlier; let me revise what I mean by $DTIME(2^{O(f(n))})$. I mean the union over all $C>0$ of $DTIME(2^{Cf(n)})$.

So what I'm really asking is whether there is some $f$, some $C$, and some language $L \in DTIME(2^{Cf(n)})$ such that $L \notin DSPACE(f(n))$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $\mathsf{L} = \mathsf{P}$ then $\mathsf{DSPACE}(O(f(n))) = \mathsf{DTIME}(2^{O(f(n)})$ for all time-constructible functions $f(n) \geq \log n$ using standard padding arguments. I am not sure what happens if $f(n)$ is not time-constructible.

If $\mathsf{L} \neq \mathsf{P}$ then $f(n) = \log n$ will be an example. Therefore there is a time-constructable function $f(n)$ where the containment is proper iff the containment is proper for $f(n) = \log n$ .